# Horde webmail install - 'webmail-install not found'

Tags: debian, webmail, pear, horde

I'm trying to install Horde Webmail on my Debian server, but I got stuck on error. I followed manual on http://www.horde.org/apps/webmail/docs/INSTALL. After installing through pear, I'm supposed to run `webmail-install` script, but it's not found.

Here's my install log

```
mailserver:/var/www/horde# pear run-scripts horde/horde_role
Including external post-installation script "/usr/share/php/PEAR/Installer/Role/Horde/Role.php" - any errors are in this script
Inclusion succeeded
running post-install script "Horde_Role_postinstall->init()"
init succeeded
Filesystem location for the base Horde application : /var/www/horde/
Configuration successfully saved to PEAR config.
Install scripts complete

mailserver:/var/www/horde# pear install -a -B horde/webmail
Package "pear.horde.org/horde" dependency "pear.horde.org/Horde_Rpc" has no releases
WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlus"
Failed to download pear/Date_Holidays within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.21.8, stability "alpha", use "channel://pear.php.net/Date_Holidays-0.21.8" to install
Failed to download pear/Text_CAPTCHA within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.4.5, stability "alpha", use "channel://pear.php.net/Text_CAPTCHA-0.4.5" to install
Failed to download pear/Text_LanguageDetect within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.3.0, stability "alpha", use "channel://pear.php.net/Text_LanguageDetect-0.3.0" to install
Unknown remote channel: pear.phpunit.de
horde/horde requires package "horde/Horde_Rpc" (version >= 2.0.0, version <= 3.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 3.0.0alpha1)
horde/webmail requires package "horde/horde" (version >= 5.0.3, version <= 6.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 6.0.0alpha1)
horde/imp requires package "horde/horde" (version >= 5.0.0, version <= 6.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 6.0.0alpha1)
horde/ingo requires package "horde/horde" (version >= 5.0.0, version <= 6.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 6.0.0alpha1)
horde/kronolith requires package "horde/horde" (version >= 5.0.0, version <= 6.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 6.0.0alpha1)
horde/kronolith can optionally use package "pear/Date_Holidays" (version >= 0.21.0)
horde/mnemo requires package "horde/horde" (version >= 5.0.0, version <= 6.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 6.0.0alpha1)
horde/nag requires package "horde/horde" (version >= 5.0.0, version <= 6.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 6.0.0alpha1)
horde/turba requires package "horde/horde" (version >= 5.0.0, version <= 6.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 6.0.0alpha1)
horde/Horde_Core can optionally use package "pear/Text_CAPTCHA"
horde/Horde_Core can optionally use package "pear/Text_LanguageDetect"
horde/Horde_Test requires package "channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit" (version >= 3.5.0)
downloading content-2.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download content-2.0.1.tgz (21,221 bytes)
........done: 21,221 bytes
downloading timeobjects-2.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download timeobjects-2.0.2.tgz (297,260 bytes)
...done: 297,260 bytes
downloading Horde_Core-2.1.7.tgz ...
Starting to download Horde_Core-2.1.7.tgz (1,395,146 bytes)
...done: 1,395,146 bytes
downloading Horde_Form-2.0.3.tgz ...
Starting to download Horde_Form-2.0.3.tgz (191,659 bytes)
...done: 191,659 bytes
downloading Horde_Timezone-1.0.2.tgz ...
Starting to download Horde_Timezone-1.0.2.tgz (20,042 bytes)
...done: 20,042 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.horde.org/Horde_Core-2.1.7
install ok: channel://pear.horde.org/Horde_Timezone-1.0.2
install ok: channel://pear.horde.org/content-2.0.1
install ok: channel://pear.horde.org/timeobjects-2.0.2
install ok: channel://pear.horde.org/Horde_Form-2.0.3

mailserver:/var/www/horde# webmail-install
-bash: webmail-install: command not found
```

Does anyone know where the problem may be and how to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a find / -name webmail-install ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for inconveniences, there was probably some problem on horde.org side. It was on and off all day and something didn't download correctly. After running *pear install -a -B horde/webmail* for millionth time, *webmail-install* script downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a program it must either be on your `$PATH`, or you must specify the *full path* to the program.
Specify the full path to the `webmail-install` script and it will work.